# Regex (JS) — Match any 5-character combination, but ignore 5-character repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

I struggle with regular expressions, and I've been trying to make one that can match any 5-character combination of `X` and `O`, but ignore it if it repeats `X` or `O` EXACTLY 5 times.

This is what I came up with:

```
X{1,4}|O{1,4}
X|O{1,4}
```

those expressions match  (I want it to ignore the XXXXX and OOOOO):
[image]

I also tried using the non-capturing group `(?:)`, but it didn't work out too well.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with regex specifically? I think it would be easier without it.

Comment: @elclanrs I'm making a 5x5 tic-tac-toe with OOP JS.  There are thousands of combos, and idk how else to look for a match.  Basically, this is looking for a tie, with no XXXXX or OOOOO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?!(.)\1+$)[XO]{5}$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uK9cD8/1

Answer (score 2):

You may try the below assertion based regex.

```
^(?!(?:X{5}|O{5})$)(?=.*X)(?=.*O)[XO]{5}$
```